# Different between direct embedded and use @ simple

Tags: android

I am trying to create a button style which includes customize background and pressed background changes response. I have done it by using the  and drawable.

The style

```
<style name="BoltButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/gree_btn_background</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
</style>
```

/drawable/gree_btn_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/btn_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/btn_focuse"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/btn_green"/>
</selector>
```

The above setting works, then I try to remove the drawable file and try to put it directly under `<item name="android:background"></item>`, error comes out, so what is the different between using `@` and directly use it? Why the above case didn't work?

The below code doesn't work

```
<item name="android:background">
      <selector >
        <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/bolt_btn_pressed"/>
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/bolt_btn_focuse"/>
        <item android:drawable="@color/bolt_btn_green"/>
      </selector>
</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<item name="android:background"></item>` inside that, its expecting id for the drawable, not the `<selector>`.

so we should give the drawable id which you give earlier `<item name="android:background">@drawable/gree_btn_background</item>`

Comment: You mean I can't use <selector> in <item>?

Comment: Inside </style> tag you can't use.